# Veritcal Drop Down Css Menu not functioning as expected

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Ok so I grabbed a CSS menu and have been tweaking it to work out how it works. I have added a couple of drop down items to it and they worked fine, but im trying to add a forth / fifth item (depending how you look at it) and I just cant get it working. The "fourth" item in the list doesn't drop down as expected.

Source of menu: http://cssmenumaker.com/menu/slabbed-accordion-menu

Can anyone explain?

**The HTML File**

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang=''>
<head>
<meta charset='utf-8'>
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="script.js"></script>
<title>CSS Menu</title>
</head>
<body>

<div id='cssmenu'>
<ul>
<li class='active has-sub'><a href='#'><span>Top</span></a>
  <ul>
     <li class='has-sub'><a href='#'><span>First Top</span></a>
        <ul>
           <li class='has-sub'><a href='#'><span>Second</span></a>
           <ul>
             <li class="has-sub"><a><span>Third</span></a></li>
             <ul>
                 <li class='last'><a href='#'><span>Fourth</span></a></li>
              </ul>
          </ul>
        </ul>
     </li>
      </ul>
   </li>
</ul>
</div>

</body>
<html>
```

**style.css**

```
    #cssmenu,
#cssmenu ul,
#cssmenu ul li,
#cssmenu ul li a {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  list-style: none;
  line-height: 1;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
#cssmenu {
  width: 200px;
  font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  color: #ffffff;
}
#cssmenu ul ul {
  display: none;
}
.align-right {
  float: right;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li > a {
  padding: 15px 20px;
  border-left: 1px solid #1682ba;
  border-right: 1px solid #1682ba;
  border-top: 1px solid #1682ba;
  cursor: pointer;
  z-index: 2;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #ffffff;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.35);
  background: #36aae7;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#36aae7, #1fa0e4);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(#36aae7, #1fa0e4);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(#36aae7, #1fa0e4);
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(#36aae7, #1fa0e4);
  background: linear-gradient(#36aae7, #1fa0e4);
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15);
}
#cssmenu > ul > li > a:hover,
#cssmenu > ul > li.active > a,
#cssmenu > ul > li.open > a {
  color: #eeeeee;
  background: #1fa0e4;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#1fa0e4, #1992d1);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(#1fa0e4, #1992d1);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(#1fa0e4, #1992d1);
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(#1fa0e4, #1992d1);
  background: linear-gradient(#1fa0e4, #1992d1);
}
#cssmenu > ul > li.open > a {
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15), 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  border-bottom: 1px solid #1682ba;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li:last-child > a,
#cssmenu > ul > li.last > a {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #1682ba;
}
.holder {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
}
.holder::after,
.holder::before {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  width: 6px;
  height: 6px;
  right: 20px;
  z-index: 10;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-135deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(-135deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(-135deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(-135deg);
  transform: rotate(-135deg);
}
.holder::after {
  top: 17px;
  border-top: 2px solid #ffffff;
  border-left: 2px solid #ffffff;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li > a:hover > span::after,
#cssmenu > ul > li.active > a > span::after,
#cssmenu > ul > li.open > a > span::after {
  border-color: #eeeeee;
}
.holder::before {
  top: 18px;
  border-top: 2px solid;
  border-left: 2px solid;
  border-top-color: inherit;
  border-left-color: inherit;
}
#cssmenu ul ul li a {
  cursor: pointer;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #32373e;
  border-left: 1px solid #32373e;
  border-right: 1px solid #32373e;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  z-index: 1;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 13px;
  color: #eeeeee;
  background: #49505a;
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
}
#cssmenu ul ul li:hover > a,
#cssmenu ul ul li.open > a,
#cssmenu ul ul li.active > a {
  background: #424852;
  color: #ffffff;
}
#cssmenu ul ul li:first-child > a {
  box-shadow: none;
}
#cssmenu ul ul ul li:first-child > a {
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
}
#cssmenu ul ul ul li a {
  padding-left: 30px;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li > ul > li:last-child > a,
#cssmenu > ul > li > ul > li.last > a {
  border-bottom: 0;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li > ul > li.open:last-child > a,
#cssmenu > ul > li > ul > li.last.open > a {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #32373e;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li > ul > li.open:last-child > ul > li:last-child > a {
  border-bottom: 0;
}
#cssmenu ul ul li.has-sub > a::after {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  width: 5px;
  height: 5px;
  right: 20px;
  z-index: 10;
  top: 11.5px;
  border-top: 2px solid #eeeeee;
  border-left: 2px solid #eeeeee;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-135deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(-135deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(-135deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(-135deg);
    transform: rotate(-135deg);
    }
    #cssmenu ul ul li.active > a::after,
    #cssmenu ul ul li.open > a::after,
    #cssmenu ul ul li > a:hover::after {
      border-color: #ffffff;
    }
```

**script.js**

```
    ( function( $ ) {
$( document ).ready(function() {
$('#cssmenu li.has-sub>a').on('click', function(){
        $(this).removeAttr('href');
        var element = $(this).parent('li');
        if (element.hasClass('open')) {
            element.removeClass('open');
            element.find('li').removeClass('open');
            element.find('ul').slideUp();
        }
        else {
            element.addClass('open');
            element.children('ul').slideDown();
            element.siblings('li').children('ul').slideUp();
            element.siblings('li').removeClass('open');
            element.siblings('li').find('li').removeClass('open');
            element.siblings('li').find('ul').slideUp();
        }
    });

    $('#cssmenu>ul>li.has-sub>a').append('<span class="holder"></span>');

    (function getColor() {
        var r, g, b;
        var textColor = $('#cssmenu').css('color');
        textColor = textColor.slice(4);
        r = textColor.slice(0, textColor.indexOf(','));
        textColor = textColor.slice(textColor.indexOf(' ') + 1);
        g = textColor.slice(0, textColor.indexOf(','));
        textColor = textColor.slice(textColor.indexOf(' ') + 1);
        b = textColor.slice(0, textColor.indexOf(')'));
        var l = rgbToHsl(r, g, b);
        if (l > 0.7) {
            $('#cssmenu>ul>li>a').css('text-shadow', '0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .35)');
            $('#cssmenu>ul>li>a>span').css('border-color', 'rgba(0, 0, 0, .35)');
        }
        else
        {
            $('#cssmenu>ul>li>a').css('text-shadow', '0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, .35)');
            $('#cssmenu>ul>li>a>span').css('border-color', 'rgba(255, 255, 255, .35)');
        }
    })();

    function rgbToHsl(r, g, b) {
        r /= 255, g /= 255, b /= 255;
        var max = Math.max(r, g, b), min = Math.min(r, g, b);
        var h, s, l = (max + min) / 2;

        if(max == min){
            h = s = 0;
        }
        else {
            var d = max - min;
            s = l > 0.5 ? d / (2 - max - min) : d / (max + min);
            switch(max){
                case r: h = (g - b) / d + (g < b ? 6 : 0); break;
                case g: h = (b - r) / d + 2; break;
                case b: h = (r - g) / d + 4; break;
            }
            h /= 6;
        }
        return l;
    }
});
} )( jQuery );
```

**http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You closed the third list item too early. You also forgot to finish the link. See below:

The error:

```
<ul>
    <li class="has-sub"><a><span>Third</span></a></li>
        <ul>
```

Corrected:

```
<ul>
    <li class='has-sub'><a href='#'><span>Third</span></a>
        <ul>
```

Full updated code:
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/NPwaeQ

Comment: hahah sooo obvious. I didn't see it lol thank you and you introduced me to codepen. ! thanks

Comment: No problem, glad I could help. Codepen is awesome, have fun with it!